# WoW - auto walking addon (auto path)

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there any addon available some thing like I click on a location on the map and character starts moving to that location (without having to using arrows/move keys)

This feature is there in Talisman Online, every quest is shown as a link and upon clicking on it, client will detect the coordinates of the target and starts moving to that direction (walks in the walkable path only) not just that but once the quest is completed if we click on the quest it takes back to the NPC (where we need to handoff the quest).

Same thing when clicked on any location on the map.

Comment: I know this is not what you're asking for, but when I played WoW briefly, I used an addon that would show footsteps to follow to the next location.  I believe it was called quest helper.  This could be useful if you're having issues figuring out how to get from A to B.  Probably useless if you're trying to save yourself some keystrokes and time.

Comment: Auto-movement in WoW would be problematic (outside the ToS violation) because it wouldn't know to avoid either mobs or other players (if you're on a PvP server), so you'd just end up being a zombie snack for something.

Comment: My first was Talisman Online, it had this feature, WoW is my 2nd MMORPG, **for me** its a big missing feature :| what ever reason it is not allowed. Thanks for sharing thoughts

Comment: While I can't state why the developer feels this way, I would have to believe that Blizzard (and most large MMOs) are under the philosophy that the player requires agency in order to be "playing" the game. This makes it easier to catch/ban bots that (in most cases) tend to have a negative impact on the game as a whole.  It's easier to have a rule that can blanket over the domain of bots then trying to make a fine line between player automation and automated player.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No.**  Automatic movement/navigation is against the terms of service in World of Warcraft, as it can be used by "bots" to farm profession materials.

It could be worse, though - quest locations didn't even show up on the map originally!  You just had to figure out where to go from the description in the text.

Comment: If you want more visibility into where you need to move, you can look into an addon like TomTom - it puts a nice big arrow on the screen that point to your current waypoint.

Comment: [TomTom](https://mods.curse.com/addons/wow/tomtom)